# Navigation item button not showing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift2

**Question:** navigation buttont not showing

I am really stuck with navigation controller.

Here is my code for navigation controller in Appdelegate:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
    SVProgressHUD.setDefaultMaskType(SVProgressHUDMaskType.Black)
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller:ViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController
    navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
    window?.rootViewController = navigation
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true

}
```

So this navigation controller worked upto last screen and in my last screen I want to make slider so I call one function in my `viewdidload` in

```
myqueto viewcontroller



 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 self.addSlideMenuButton()

}
```

and main thing is I derive "myquetoviewcontroller" from "baseviewcontroller"

```
class myquoetoViewController: BaseViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
```

and this is the function in `baseview controller`

```
 func addSlideMenuButton(){
    let btnShowMenu = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
    btnShowMenu.setImage(self.defaultMenuImage(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    btnShowMenu.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
    btnShowMenu.addTarget(self, action: "onSlideMenuButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    let customBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnShowMenu)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
}

func defaultMenuImage() -> UIImage {
    var defaultMenuImage = UIImage()

    struct Static {
        static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
    }

    dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken, { () -> Void in
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(30, 22), false, 0.0)

        UIColor.blackColor().setFill()
        UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0, 3, 30, 1)).fill()
        UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0, 10, 30, 1)).fill()
        UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0, 17, 30, 1)).fill()

        UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
        UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0, 4, 30, 1)).fill()
        UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0, 11,  30, 1)).fill()
        UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0, 18, 30, 1)).fill()

        defaultMenuImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    })

    return defaultMenuImage;
}
```

So how should i manage this.. and one more thing is slider working correctly its just not showing `navigationbaritem` buttons icon..

[image: this is what i got]

[image: this is what i want]

Comment: are you using reveal view controller ?

Comment: please check below answer for navigating you need to pass revealviewcontroller storyboard id.

Answer (score 0):

So add in storyboard id for reveal view controller like RevealVC or something then

```
    let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RevealVC") as SecondViewController

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: in previous view controller have u given like this for navigating?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image:self.defaultMenuImage(),
                style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,
                target: self, action: "onSlideMenuButtonPressed:");
```